# Customize items in form select

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc

In my registration form, I have a field that give to users the possiblity to choose roles. But, I want to, only, show two roles : USER and MODERATOR. 
But, I don't know how to proceed.
this registration form jsp :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label style="color:#ffffff;" class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="userProfiles">Roles</label>
<div class="col-md-7">
<form:select  path="userProfiles" items="${roles}" multiple="true" itemValue="id" itemLabel="type" class="form-control input-sm" />
<div class="has-error">
<form:errors path="userProfiles" class="help-inline"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have an enum : UserProfileType

```
public enum UserProfileType implements Serializable{
USER("USER"),
DBA("DBA"),
ADMIN("ADMIN"),
MODERATOR("MODERATOR");

String userProfileType;

private UserProfileType(String userProfileType){
    this.userProfileType = userProfileType;
}

public String getUserProfileType(){
    return userProfileType;
}

}
```

And this is how it look :

[image: registration form]

This my controller, the part responsible of registration

```
//new user

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registrationForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newUser(User user, ModelMap model) {
        //User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "registrationForm";
    }

    //save user

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/registrationForm" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser1(@Valid User user, BindingResult result,
            ModelMap model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registrationForm";
        }
        if(!userService.isUserSSOUnique(user.getId(), user.getSsoId())){
            FieldError ssoError =new FieldError("user","ssoId",messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.ssoId", new String[]{user.getSsoId()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            result.addError(ssoError);
            return "registrationForm";
        }

        userService.saveUser(user);

        model.addAttribute("success", "User " + user.getFirstName() + " "+ user.getLastName() + " registered successfully");
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        //return "success";
        return "registrationsuccess";
    }
```

I am using spring mvc/security and hibernate.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your Spring controller must put these items in the model so just change the code at the point. Post the controller code if you need further help.

Comment: yes, exactly that what I tried to do : make some changes on the controller, but I failed. Please check the post again, I edited it

Comment: That code is of no use. Somewhere in your code you populate a collection of roles. That is not it.

Comment: I am sorry, do you mean the part where the mapping of the individual userProfile id’s on view to actual UserProfile Entities in database ?

Comment: Where do you imagine the roles in the dropdown come from??????????????

Comment: I am still new to spring, so I am trying to learn new things, roles for example.
I  filtered the roles in the view, even though  it's not recommanded, but, it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data  to be displayed by the page should be provided and manipulated by the controller. Filter the roles in your controller before handing over to the view.

Depending on how you are adding attributes to the model you can do it as foLlows (or any equivalent way as Spring MVC is flexible)

You could create methods in your Enum class to return the filtered values according to yours needs:

```
public enum UserProfileType implements Serializable{
USER("USER"),
DBA("DBA"),
ADMIN("ADMIN"),
MODERATOR("MODERATOR");

   String userProfileType;

    private UserProfileType(String userProfileType){
        this.userProfileType = userProfileType;
    }

    public String getUserProfileType(){
        return userProfileType;
    }

    public static List<UserProfileType> getAdminRoles(){
        return Arrays.asList(UserProfileType.USER , UserProfileType.MODERATOR);
    }

}

@ModelAttribute("roles")
public List<UserProfileType> roles(){
   return UserProfileType.getAdminRoles();
}
```

You can also filter the roles in the view but its not recommended to have control logic in your view

```
<form:select  path="userProfiles"multiple="true"  class="form-control input-sm">
   <c:forEach items="${roles}" var = "role">
      <c:if test="${role.type eq 'USER' or role.type eq 'MODERATOR'}">
         <form:option value="${role.id}" label="${role.type}"/>
      </c:if>
   </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

Comment: In fact, I've tried the second solution, since it's easy, but, instead of showing the role names, it shows their IDs.
However, the first one, I don't really get it, I don't how to use this or call this in the controller.
Please check the post again, I edited it

Comment: There was an error. I have just updated this part <form:option value="${role.id}" label="${role.type}"/>